# MDT: Windows 10 Upgrade - Unknown command-line option [/auto] was specified

Tags: mdt, windows-10, mdt-2013

I am using MDT 2013 Update 1 to perform upgrades to Windows 10 within my enterprise.  I am using the "Upgrade Task Sequence".  The deployments are failing but they don't seem to be MDT related, they are windows setup related.
The error is:

> An unknown command-line option [/auto] was specified.

I have looked at the logs and it doesn't seem to like the "/auto upgrade" command-line option.  I have tried running the setup manually as follows setup.exe /auto upgrade and I get the same error.
The media is downloaded from our subscription on the VLSC.

Any ideas?

Comment: Microsoft pulled the initial release of MDT update 1. Make sure you get bits after September 15th

Comment: Can I check this with version numbers? MDT was only installed a couple of days ago - so I would imagine I have the right stuff.

Comment: What link did you get MDT from?

Comment: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48595